# How to catch the "slice bounds out of range" error and write a handle for it

Tags: go

I read other questions about the "slice bounds of range" here in the stackoverflow, but none of them using the same context from this.
Then, none of the answers helped me.

In my use case, the "golang's syntax" of substring using [] doesn't return an error variable. It launches a runtime error using the "panic" instruction.
My goal is to avoid to reach on the "panic" instruction.
I need to treat this error and provide messages that describe with more details the context around the moment where this error had occurred.

Obs:
The content of the string variable which one I need to get the substring value is totally dynamic and the indexes that I have been using to get the substring value is equally calculated dynamically.

Comment: Use the `len` built-in to find the length of the string and don't try to index past that index.

Comment: As Tim said, best is to use `len()` before indexing or slicing, to avoid out-of-range indices. If the code is out of your hands, you may use `recover()` to recover from such panics, but first try to add checks before toucing `recover()`.

Comment: Thank you (Tim Cooper and Icza) for your comments. The approach you put on the table is really good and simple. The treatment before to substring call because I can forecast whether the problem will occur or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do bounds checking on your indexes:

```
if j >= 0 && j <= len(str) {
   y = str[:j]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  It has the same approach from the comments from Tim Cooper and Icza above. This solution is good and simple. Exactly what I wanted.